# GNU Octave: 'shape' is undefined even when it's defined as a function parameter

Tags: undefined, octave, function-definition

I wrote a simple drag simulation program, just incorporating a drag formula and a few presets for coefficients. I seem to be having problems with one of the variables not being defined. I have found one other question with the same problem as I do, but none of the answers are working for me. Here's my code:

```
function drag = drag_calc(area_var, shape, density, velocity)
  shape_area = 0;
  drag_C = 0;

  fprintf("%s\n", shape);

  if (strcmp(shape, "sphere"))
      shape_area = 4 * pi * area_var^2;
      drag_C = 0.47;
  elseif (strcmp(shape, "sphere"))
      shape_area = area_var(1) * area_var(2);
      drag_C = 1.05;
  else
      shape_area = 1;
      drag_C = 1;
  endif

  drag = calc_drag(drag_C, shape_area, density, velocity);
endfunction

function drag_Force = calc_drag(drag_C, shape_area, density, velocity)

  drag_Force = (1/2) * drag_C * shape_area * density * velocity;
endfunction

velocity = 0:0.5:100;

drag = drag_calc(2, "sphere", 1.8, velocity);

plot(velocity, drag);
```

I am aware that to call functions from another script I need to state the name of the file I am referencing, although it still says the same variable is undefined. Calling the function from the command line doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an issue with how you define functions in a file.

If this is a script file, start it with `1;` at the top, before defining your first function. That way Octave will recognize it as a script file rather than a function file.

If the first line of code is a function definition, that file will be seen as a function file, and using its name on the command line will execute that first function, not your script at the end.

Comment: I did partially figure it out where I realized if I didn't have the first line of code in the file as a function, it would actually work, but what exactly are the differences between a function and script file? Also my functions don't seem to work if I put them in a separate file and try to run them from another file, the same error occurs

Comment: Actually I think I realize now that I "called" the function file I wanted to use in another script at the beginning, leading the function to be defined at the beginning of the file as well in that circumstance, so I think that would definitely help, thanks!